# How to get or return only the matching object from an nested array using mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

```
{
"_id": "6339f99ee18b2481a04b4fe8",
"userId": "60a8a51cf2229813a45d2238",
"array1": [
    {
        "someId1": "6339f99ee18b2481a04b4fe9",
        "customIndex": 2,
        "array2": [
            {
                "someId2": "6339f99ee18b2481a04b4fea",
                "startDate": 2022-10-10T19:56:26.000+00:00,
                "endDate": 2022-10-12T19:56:26.000+00:00,
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "someId1": "6345ca40112b743fd8172be0",
        "customIndex": 4,
        "array2": [
            {
                "someId2": "6345ca40112b743fd8172be1",
                "startDate": 2022-10-10T19:56:26.000+00:00,
                "endDate": 2022-10-27T19:56:26.000+00:00,
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have above structure in mongoDB and want to get only that object from `array1` which matches the conditions of `endDate` > `2022-10-17`

Here's what I try to do:

```
result= await Collection.find({
  userId: { '$in': userIdList},
  'array1.array2.endDate': { "$gte": 2022-10-17}
})
```

But above return the **both objects from array1** even though the `endDate` for one object is less than `2022-10-17`

How can I get the the response like below? Also, Am I using the right Mongoose calls to achieve what I am trying to achieve.

Expected response that I am trying to achieve:

```
{
"_id": "6339f99ee18b2481a04b4fe8",
"userId": "60a8a51cf2229813a45d2238",
"array1": [
    {
        "someId1": "6345ca40112b743fd8172be0",
        "customIndex": 4,
        "array2": [
            {
                "someId2": "6345ca40112b743fd8172be1",
                "startDate": 2022-10-10T19:56:26.000+00:00,
                "endDate": 2022-10-27T19:56:26.000+00:00,
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Can array1 contain more than one matching item? Can array2 contain more than one matching item?

Answer (score 0):

If `array1` can contain several such items, and `array2` contain several such items, one option is using `$reduce` with `$filter` and `$mergeObjects` for this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {userId: {'$in': userIdList}}}
  {$project: {
      userId: 1,
      array1: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$array1",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {$concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              [{$mergeObjects: [
                    "$$this",
                    {array2: {
                        $filter: {
                          input: "$$this.array2",
                          as: "innerItem",
                          cond: {$gte: [
                              "$$innerItem.endDate",
                              {$dateFromParts: {year: 2022, month: 10, day: 17}}
                          ]}
                        }
                    }}
            ]}]
          ]}
        }
      }
  }},
  {$project: {
      userId: 1,
      array1: {$filter: {
          input: "$array1",
          cond: {$gt: [{$size: "$$this.array2"}, 0]}
      }}
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jQHpPOR5fzX)